# F# Generic sum type constraints

Tags: generics, f#, type-constraints

What is the proper way to write type constraints for a generic type so that we can have its instance passed to the `Array.sum` function?

This does not work:

```
let mySum< 'a when 'a : (static member get_Zero: unit -> 'a) and 'a : (static member (+) : 'a -> 'a -> 'a) > (xs: 'a[]) = Array.sum xs
```

The error message I get for the above is `A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when  ^a : (static member get_Zero : ->  ^a)'`

Although I would need a generic type, not a statically resolved one, I did try the following, withouth success:

```
let mySum< ^a when ^a : (static member get_Zero: unit -> ^a) and ^a : (static member (+) : ^a -> ^a -> ^a) > (xs: ^a[]) = Array.sum xs
```

(I get the same error message here again). I also tried to inline the function and it did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
let inline mySum< 'a when 'a : (static member Zero :   ^a) and 'a : (static member (+) : 'a -> 'a -> 'a) > (xs: 'a[]) = Array.sum xs
```

but don't forget to mark the function inline.

Comment: Thanks, the `get_Zero`, instead of `Zero` in my attempts was the culprit.

Comment: @Gus could you please provide some good tutorials about f# generic types constraints?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, the starting point should be the official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters but from there you'll need to look for more specific blogs.